# Local-cohomology and Hom

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $f:R\to S$ be a flat homomorphism of commutative Noetherian rings. "Flat Base Change Theorem", compares the local cohomology modules $H^i_a(M) \otimes_R S$ and $H^i_{aS} (M\otimes_R S)$ for $i ∈ N_0$ and an arbitrary $R$-module $M$.
I have two questions:
**Question.1.**
 Can one generalize this? such as: for a (flat) $S$-module instead of $S$; ($H^i_{aS} (M\otimes_R N)$)?
**Question.2.** (which is more important for me)

> Is there a known fact about $H^i_{aS} (Hom_R (M,N)$?
>   In this case any (non-trivial) condition can be posed on modules and rings; (for example $R=S$)

Comment: If $R=S$, $M$ is finitely generated, and you replace Hom by RHom then $R\Gamma_a RHom_R(M,N) \cong RHom_R(M,R\Gamma_a N)$. See Lemma 3.12 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4064

Comment: is $a$ suppose to be an ideal $\mathfrak a$?  or do you mean the principal ideal generated by $a$?

Comment: it is ideal. but as in the Q. *any (non-trivial) condition can be posed*